# Anchor tag does not work properly express

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ejs

When I click on the p,nothing happens,but when I click on any other part of the div it works fine.I don't know why this is happening.Please help me.

```
<%- include('./partials/header');-%>
<%- include('./partials/flash');-%>
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
<a href="/post/<%= post._id %>" id="posta">
<div id="post">
<h3 class="text-dark" id="title"><%- post.Title %></h3>
<p class="text-secondary" id="date"><small><%=post.Author.name %><br>
<%=post._id.getTimestamp().toLocaleDateString()%></small></p>
<p class="h6 text-dark" id="Postcontent"><%- post.Content.substring(0,200)+"..." %><span class="h6 text-success">Read more</span>
</p>
</div>
</a>
<span id="border"></span>
<% }) %>
<%- include('./partials/footer');-%>
```

The css that i used:

```
#post:hover{
    box-shadow:  0 5px 5px 0 #4CAF50;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#posta:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#posta:link {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
#posta:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
#Postcontent{
  font-size: 1rem; 
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Update:
It is weird but what I observed is that when I click on the first item's p it does not work but for all the other items it works.

Link to the website:
https://enlightening-blog.herokuapp.com/

Comment: please paste the output rendered in html too so we can help you

Comment: @mamadgiaishwarya Clicking on first 'Read More" is not doing anything but other work as expected. is this your issue or its something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your codes. The issue was with the way you wrote your js code. The problem lies elsewhere than mentioned in the question (thanks to the links). The mistake you made was one of the rookie mistake (never put static id in loops). The ids are same. Based on the way js works it looks for unique ids but duplicate classes can be fine.
So your current code is

```
document.getElementById("Postcontent").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Change the *Postcontent* from id to class and add the following code

```
var postcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".Postcontent");
postcontent.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one minor mistake but important one as mentioned by @rajesh-paudel .

```
 Never user static ids in loops.
```

This code violates the standard and is therefore incorrect. It would fail validation checking, and it should.

ID must be unique. Read here : for [HTML 4.x Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)
for [HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

```
When specified on HTML elements, the id attribute value must be 
unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at 
least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.
```